# MySQL code mistaken for MSSQL and results in Intellisense syntax errors

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-code

An `.sql` file in my VS Code workspace contains MySQL code. Even though I have installed two plugins ([MySQL](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.vscode-mysql) and [MySQL Syntax](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jakebathman.mysql-syntax)), my IDE still recognizes this file with MSSQL and generates syntax errors.

[image]

Of course, this does not prevent me from running my program and I can always set the syntax highlighting to None. But I'd rather have VS Code recognize the language for all of my files.

Answer (score 15):

I had this problem. Solved it by uninstalling the mssql extension. Didn't even realise I'd installed it, but it seems I accidentally did through that 'recommended extension' popup that vscode sends up frequently. You may have installed it as well, and because mssql is Microsoft, it's overriding any other sql types.

Comment: Thanks for this! However I still need to use mssql sometimes, so instead of uninstalling I disabled it for my workspace (so I can still use it in my other workspaces). That was enough to get rid of the incorrect errors for me :-)

Comment: I don't have MSSQL extension installed. Still it doesn't recognise # as comment prefix

Comment: @IsmailS well, why would it? You need to add a MySQL extension to analyze the code. I'd rather it just ignore my sql files